# How to start typing in a textarea depending on where I click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to focus cursor in place of as I want. Can it be possible with html or css or javascript ? I have a simple textarea as

```
  <textarea name="contents" cols="100" rows="50"></textarea>
```

Now I can only focus cursor and type from top-left cornor of my textarea. But I want to focus and start type in the middle of textarea. How can I figure it out ?

*Now I am using with **Enter** keys and **Space** keys of my keboard to place my cursor.*

I want to type without using enter keys and space keys:

[image]

Comment: what the actual... what do you want? focus a textarea or center align the text in the textarea?

Comment: Tried adding `text-align: center` in CSS? I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Alex Here is screenshoot http://puu.sh/g0JD1/b6b129de8f.png what I want to type without using enter keys and space keys

Comment: That's not possible. You can only align text in a `textarea` using whitespace characters like newline and space.

Comment: so you want to start right where you click in the textarea?

Comment: @Alex yes sir ! it is what I want .

Comment: @Cataclysm, As you mentioned you can fill your textarea with spaces and then manage the spaces when you type anything.

Comment: @AshadShanto :D is it the only way to get it ? sir ...

Comment: @Cataclysm just to give you a hint, this could be really tough to do. If I were you I would  create a div everytime you click at the position where you click and make it `contenteditable`

Comment: @Alex Oh ! TextArea is an example. I can replace HTML element and edit my question. How can it be done with `div` element sir ?

Comment: @Cataclysm have a guess and try out yourself! when you dont come further, post a new question

Comment: @Alex I think [contenteditable](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_contenteditable.asp) needs to have some contents . It will not satisfy my problem.

Comment: @Cataclysm, you can try the answer I gave by filling the the textarea with spaces. Though I'm looking forward to another way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a way to fill your `textarea` with spaces and then you can type wherever you clicked on.

***jQuery :***

```
var $contentTextarea = $("textarea[name='contents']");

var cols = Number($contentTextarea.attr("cols"));
var rows = Number($contentTextarea.attr("rows"));

for(var i = 0; i < cols; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < rows; j++ ){
         $contentTextarea.append(" ");
    }
    $contentTextarea.append("\n");
}
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/bkdvL9bk/)